# How to pass choice parameter to call a job inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can I pass `choice parameters` for the downstream job when called inside a `stage` in the jenkins pipeline?

I tried the below solutions but none worked:

```
stage('build job') {
    steps{
        script{
              build job: 'test',
                   parameters: [
                                choice(choices: "option1\noption2\noption3\n", description: '', name: 'choiceParam')
                                ] 
              }
     }
}
```

fails with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterValue is using symbol ‘choice’`

Tried these as well:

```
 parameters:
   [
     [$class: 'ChoiceParameterValue', name: 'choiceParam', value: "1\n\2\n3\n"],
   ]
```

fails with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterValue is named ChoiceParameterValue`

I actually want to pass the choice parameter as a `build parameter` like "$choiceParam" for `value` so that I can just update the jenkins job configuration instead of always updating the values in the pipeline script

Can someone please help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

When you are building a job via the Build step, you are kicking it off so you need to have "selected" a value.

In this instance you would pass in the desired 'String' choice. Not a list of choices. i.e. "1"

We create our list of params and then pass that in. So: our current job has these input params:

```
choice(name: 'ENV', choices: product, description: 'Env'),
choice(name: 'ENV_NO', choices: envParams(product), description: 'Env No'),
```

We pass these downstream by setting them:

```
List<ParameterValue> newParams = [
    new StringParameterValue('ENV', params.ENV),
    new StringParameterValue('ENV_NO', params.ENV_NO),
]
build(job: "job", parameters: newParams, propagate: false)
```